# Why Celery Chain not throw an Exception when the underlying task throws one?

Tags: python, celery, chain

i am having set of tasks

```
def add(x,y)
    try:
        return x+y
    except Exception:
        raise Exception('No result')
def mul(x,y)
    try:
        raise Exception('Error')
    except Exception:
        raise Exception('No result')
def sub(x,y)
    try:
        return x-y
    except Exception:
        raise Exception('No result')
```

i am chaining all the tasks

```
try:
    runner = []
    runner.append(
        signature(
            add(2,2)
        ),
    )
    runner.append(
        signature(
            mul(2,2)
        ),
    )
    runner.append(
        signature(
            sub(3,3)
        ),
    )
    runner = chain(*runner).apply_async()
    waitForTask(runner)
except Exception:
    return False
```

i created a function to wait until all the tasks finished

```
    def waitForTask(task):
        """
        Wait ultil task finished.

        Attributes:
          task: celery task

        Returns:
            Boolean: True
        """
        while True:
            time.sleep(config.defaults['delay'])
            if task.ready():
                break
        return True
```

error raised at task`sub` i need to get the task exception in chain `except` block
sorry for my poor english
Thanks in advance

Comment: In your `mul` function, you are raising `Exceptions` in both cases. Why is that?

Comment: @RedowanDelowar its for example if unexpected error occurred and exception raised

Comment: Your intent is not clear. Do you want to catch the error that happens inside `mul` from the chain? What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: @RedowanDelowar If error occur in `mul` . then `mul` will raise `Exception` then in the `chain` if `Exception` raised in any one of the task remaining tasks are stopped and `task` -> `exception` has to be caught in `chain` -> `exception` and finally `chain` `exception` has `return False`